# Limiting amount of selected rows based on sort column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following tables:

- Compounds
- Lots
- Tests

A compound can have multiple lots and each lot can have multiple tests. A test has a test_date.

I want to select the first 100 compounds when sorted by test_date in descending order.

The difficulty is that a compound can appear multiple times when just doing a basic sorting because it has multiple lots each with multiple tests. I tried with analytics function (row_number, rank and dense_rank) but they alone can't seem to achieve what I want.

```
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tests.test_date DESC NULLS LAST) AS row_number,
    compounds.compound_id
FROM
    compounds
INNER JOIN 
    lots
    ON compounds.compound_id = lots.compound_id
INNER JOIN 
    tests
    ON lots.lot_id = tests.lot_id

ORDER BY tests.test_date DESC NULLS LAST
```

But again this doesn't work as I would want each compound returned only once with the first one being the one that had the last test.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @MatBailie Oracle does not support the `LIMIT` keyword. From Oracle 12 they would use `FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: it's not a basic top n question. please read the question in full.

Comment: the question closed moments before I could click post on the answer I had entered below, essentially flipping your query around and grouping at the detail level, then joining to the higher level details should remove the duplication you are seeing:
```SELECT   L.compound_id
   ,MAX(T.test_date) AS latest_test
FROM   Tests T
INNER JOIN  Lots L ON L.lot_id = T.lot_id
INNER JOIN  Compounds C ON C.compound_id = L.compound_id
GROUP BY  L.compound_id
ORDER BY  MAX(T.test_date) DESC
FETCH FIRST  100 ROWS ONLY;```

Comment: The question had not been tagged with `top-n`, it had been tagged with `greatest-n-per-group` because you state "I would want each compound returned only once with the first one being the one that had the last test." Which appears to be a `greatest-n-per-group` question. If it is not then explain why. Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with the: `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data; an English (not code) explanation of how you want the sample data to be transformed; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: However, "I want to select the first 100 compounds when sorted by test_date in descending order." does make it look very much like a `top-n` question. Again, providing a [MRE] with a worked example showing your expected output would help clarify the question.